# Fame Rate Going Down

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

When I get to a higher fame level. It don't get as much fame. I got a character. I was playing with my fiend in a dungeon. In the dungeon he got 50 fame I got 25. Does anyone know why.

Comment: haha I misread this as "frame rate going down"

Comment: Lol I would probably do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm assuming that you were talking about base fame, the amount of fame that a character has while they're still alive.  Base fame can be viewed by mousing over the fame bar located above the hp bar.)

After you reach around 350 base fame, the rate at which experience converts to fame slows down significantly.